# Too many thread pools with few threads in each pool

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

My tomcat server always stop serving due to too many threads, after debugging with `jstack`, I just find there are too many `WAITING` threads (see below), and looks there are belong to different thread pool (3787, 3786, 3786), so where is the problem, why it create so many pools but not reuse existing thread pool?

```
"pool-3787-thread-1" #7095 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5605286800 nid=0x6d81 waiting on condition [0x00007f55842ae000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
         at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
         - parking to wait for  <0x00000006fd51fb70> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
         at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
         at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
         at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

 "pool-3786-thread-1" #7094 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f55cdb62000 nid=0x6d80 waiting on condition [0x00007f55843af000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
         at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
         - parking to wait for  <0x00000006fd5203e8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
         at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
         at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
         at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

 "pool-3785-thread-1" #7093 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5610e68800 nid=0x6d7f waiting on condition [0x00007f55844b0000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
         at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
         - parking to wait for  <0x00000006fd520c60> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
         at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
         at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
         at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### UPDATE

Here is the `server.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->

<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
maxThreads="350" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" emptySessionPath="true"
   connectionTimeout="20000" enableLookups="false" maxPostSize="0"
                  redirectPort="8443"  URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
<!--
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" /> -->
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: Are you using any `Executor` or `ExecutorService`, if so, see how are you using them and may need to call the `shutdown()` on them.

Comment: @RP- thanks for your response, i just updated my question with server.xml, please feel free to let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The executors in server.xml has `catalina-exec-` prefix, in your thread-dump the thread pools are from executor service, may be started from some part of your application or some third party library you are using. You need to check them.

Comment: you mean this line `<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"` ?, If so, I don't think so, since this line is commented out.

Comment: so, though I configured executor with `<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"`, I didn't configure `tomcatThreadPool` in xml, is it the root cause?

Comment: oops, it my mistake, but I still feel these are custom executors as Tomcat or any other famous libraries name their thread pools properly, the names in your question are default ones. See if there are any other thread pool names in your dump.

Comment: yes, I can also find `MongoCleaner...`, `http-apr-8080-Poller` and so on, but 90% + threads named with `pool-xxxx-thread-1`

Comment: How are the thread pools named? "pool-3786-thread-1" -> Probably misleading to think there are 3.7K pools

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just get some insight after discussing with @RP-, thanks in advance.

The root cause can be quite different from each other, in my case, the root case is `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200);`, I just run this code every time when want to run async task, and don't call `shutdown()`.

Comment: Is this part of the question or an answer?  Are you really running `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200);` in a loop like this implies?  That's a strange pattern for sure.